# Maximum likelihood estimator for a discontinuous PDF

Tags: probability, maximum-likelihood

Suppose I have a PDF with the following distribution: $\theta$ between $[-1, 0]$ and $(1-\theta)$ between $[0,1]$.

How can I calculate the MLE estimator for $\theta$ in this setting? My first approach would be to treat this distribution as if it were a Bernoulli, but it is not quite right, so I am insecure about that.

Comment: A discontinuity with respect to the random value (say $x$) doesn't cause any problem, because you don't differentiate with respect to $x$, only with respect to $\theta$.   It *is* quite like a Bernoulli, in the sense that the likelihood  has only two possible values for any $\theta$.

Comment: You are right, thanks! I was worried about calculating the variance of this distribution and how it would be different from a Bernoulli. But for the purpose of the MLE, this is not necessary at all. My mistake. Thank again :)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3216935/321264

Comment: You don't describe a valid PDF.  If we interpret your first line to mean you have a function $f$ with $f(x)=\theta$ for $x\in[-1,0]$ and $f(x)=1-\theta$ for $x\in[0,1],$ then $\int_{-1}^1 f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x = 2.$ There may be other interpretations of that line, but it's hard to tell what.

Comment: @Stubborn Yes, you're right.  (I somehow read a "$1+\theta$" into the first part of the definition in place of "$\theta.$")